# Incorrect Meta information in Google

Tags: google-search

Google shows up incorrect meta info (title & description) in search engine results for an add domain and the information is of the domain which is the primary domain of the hosting account. I mentioned this fact because add-on domains are in a sub-directory of the primary domain.

Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: Can you provide the names of the domains in question?

Comment: @danlefree added to the question, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is something wrong with Google's cached copy of the site - the "Cached" link throws an error on that search.

Do you see any crawl errors or inconsistencies in Google Webmaster Tools for the domain?

---

**Update:**

Google's cache of the site shows the content from your primary domain - my best guess would be that this issue will resolve itself once Googlebot revisits your domain *unless* there is an issue with the site's configuration.

If you do not have administrative access to  you should investigate the site's configuration with the administrator: if requests with a Googlebot user agent show irregular content lengths in the webserver logs, check the site's scripts and webserver configuration for any directives which are conditionally presenting the main site's content. (could be a case of un/intentional [page cloaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking))

Comment: I have just suggested the site owner to use GWT, any more suggestions?

Comment: @Ashfame - See answer for updates - the fact that the Google cache was missing suggests it was a hiccup on Google's part.

Comment: This seems the most logical reason and match with my understanding of the problem, so I am marking this as the anwswer. The site owner has moved the site now and the problem will resolve away anyway now.

Answer (score 0):

Google displays a title and snippet in its search results.

Google has the right to display anything in those spots.

If the pages title tag and meta description match well with the users search and the pages content, then they tend to use them.

If not, they may look into the content, or even further to find relevant text to display.

So, I would assume your title & description don't match well with the search or content.

Comment: I understand they may show up different from what we have specified in tags (still choosing from what we have on page as content) but they won't randomly pick the meta tags of another domain's page. Make sense?